# Native to the land USA?

Tags: usa, culture, cultural-awareness

What is the local culture of USA, like in South Africa, we have isiXhosa's and isiZulu's etc... So what are native culture groups around North America USA.

Comment: Just a suggestion: it seems you are asking a lot about things everyone wonders when travelling to a specific destination, so these answers are provided in guidebooks. I think you should start by reading one, before asking too basic questions on this site. This site is more tailored for questions not handled elsewhere, especially not in guidebooks. For example, http://wikitravel.org/en/North_America http://www.lonelyplanet.com/usa will at least help you narrow what you really want to know. Then feel free to come ask if anyone knows how to meet a specific people, that no guidebook tells about.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a travel problem that you face, as per the [faq].  It appears to be just a general question about culture, and is something you could easily find on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Americans_in_the_United_States).  It's not a well formed question for this site, and doesn't appear to have a travel purpose, so I'm closing it.

Answer (score 4):

You can read all about it on [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_Americans_in_the_United_States). There exist tourist attractions associated with the native culture. For example, you could visit the [Navajo Nation](http://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Navajo_Nation), the largest reservation inside the contiguous United States.

It includes native Americans in the contiguous United States, [pacific islanders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacific_Islander), [Inuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inuit) in Alaska, and other groups.